# Получение get параметра в nginx

Tags: nginx

Нужно в nginx получить get параметр.

Например при запросе на http://my-example.loc/page1?foo=123
в конфиге nginx-а получить этот URL, get параметр `foo` и присвоить его в переменную.

Понимаю что задача элементарная, но от написания конфигов для nginx-а очень далек.

Comment: такая переменная уже существует, называется [`arg_foo`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_)

Comment: @diraria ответы в ответы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь переменной [`arg_имяпараметра`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_). В вашем случае `arg_foo`.

Также существует переменная [`args`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_args), в которой хранится полная строка аргументов.

---

Чтобы проверить, был ли параметр передан, можно воспользоваться `if`-ом:

```
if ($arg_foo) {
    rewrite ... break;
}
```

Или чтобы проверить, параметр на какое-то конкретное значение:

```
if ($arg_foo = bar) {
    rewrite ... break;
}
```